# What is the role of the differential amplifier in a delta sigma converter?

Tags: amplifier, differential

A differential amplifier amplifies the difference between the two input voltages but suppresses any voltage common to the two inputs. Based on this scheme

[image]

the differential amplifier is substracting an input with a delayed input and outputing a tiny difference to the integrator and that is confusing. So as mentioned in the title, how does the differential amplifier behave or whats is its role here?

**Note**: am a beginner fascinated by electronics, bear with me.

Comment: Maybe if I call that "Difference Amp" an **Error amplifier** it is easier to understand what it does. It amplifies the **error** between the input signal \$X_1\$ and the feedback signal \$X_5\$. The Difference Amp tries to make \$X_5\$ = \$X_1\$. Let's say that \$X_1\$ = 4 and \$X_5\$ = 3, that means a difference = error = 1 as \$X_5\$ is 1 too low. Then \$X_2\$ will get a value such that \$X_3\$, \$X_4\$ and eventually \$X_5\$ will all increase in value such that \$X_5\$ increases from 3 to 4, then \$X_5\$ = \$X_1\$ = 4

Comment: You posted this on [codidact](https://electrical.codidact.com/questions/279600), and it looks like you already have an answer there, from 14h ago (from now). Why post it again, here?

Comment: And an answer even from the legendary Olin, so you're in luck!

Comment: In any case, this is hardly an obscure design and well described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-sigma_modulation) among other places.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I liked the way you explained it to me but what about time difference between X1 & X5?

Comment: Do you know how a successive approximation ADC works (as asked elsewhere).

Comment: You need to have more of an idea about it before tackling sigma delta ADCs

Comment: *what about time difference between X1 & X5* What I described holds for signals that are **slow to change**, then the system will have enough time to make \$X_1 = X_5\$. With faster signals, \$X_5\$ will "lag behind", the error will increase but so will \$X_2\$, the output of the difference amp. That will make the system change faster. The timing difference doesn't matter as long as it is **small enough**. If it gets too large then your input signal **changes too fast** for this converter, you're close to its bandwidth.

Comment: Realize that SD converters **are not easy to fully understand** especially for a beginner in electronics. Also there is generally no need to fully understand them unless you're designing your own. To design your own, usually a Master's in EE and some experience is required. Go find out how many books are written about sigma-delta (or delta-sigma) converters. There are many. That means, it is a complex subject.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie you are an EE and you know that almost all equations in electronics include times. yes i can search the web for a schematic an build it but what can i say am not that type of person REASON is my flag

Comment: The output isn't the delayed input. And the difference isn't tiny.

Comment: It's the Delta. The integrator after it is the Sigma.

Answer (score 1):

The loop involving the -ve input of the difference amplifier has a collossal gain, thanks to the integrator and comparator. It therefore has enough gain that the loop will **do whatever it takes (tm)** to keep the two inputs of the differential amplifier at the same voltage, on average.

As one of its inputs is coming from the 1-bit DAC which is either +Vref or -Vref, its output (assuming unity gain) will be jumping between x1+Vref and x1-Vref, in such a way that the averaged output is zero (we know it's zero because the integrator output stays bounded). As x1 changes, the relative density of x1+Vref and x1-Vref must change to keep the output on average zero.

Comment: UK" to keep the two inputs of the differential amplifier at the same voltage, on average."   So lets put that in practice lets say that our circuit is PERFECT and we applied a VERY constant voltage of 5.000v DC, and the diff amp is IDEAL which result in a same voltage at the two inputs of the differential amplifier so the Integrator gonna receive ZERO difference all time. Now let assume that at the same circuit no potential is applied to the input 0.000v the output of our PERFECT circuit will be the same. So zero output from diff amp. your opinion does matter.

Comment: @autodidact I don't understand your question. Have you read the second paragraph of my answer?

Answer (score 0):

It calculates the input minus the output.

See the integrator in the middle? This type of ADC works by trying to keep the average (input minus output) voltage equal to zero. If the average is bigger than 0, the output is positive (so the average goes down). If the average is less than 0, the output is negative (so the average goes up).

The output usually doesn't equal the input at any point. Only the average output equals the average input. Then, a digital circuit calculates the average output, which (as I just said) is equal to the average input. Therefore it knows the average input - assuming that the circuit is much faster than the input, so the "average input" and "actual input" are almost the same.

Comment: user253751 "This type of ADC works by trying to keep the average (input minus output) voltage equal to zero ."   So lets put that in practice lets say that our circuit is PERFECT and we applied a VERY constant voltage of 5.000v DC, and the diff amp is IDEAL which result in a same voltage at the two inputs of the differential amplifier so the Integrator gonna receive ZERO difference all time. Now let assume that at the same circuit no potential is applied to the input 0.000v the output of our PERFECT circuit will be the same. So zero output from diff amp. your opinion does matter to.

Comment: @autodidact If the supply is 5V and the input is 5V and all components are perfect, the output from the diff-amp will be 0. But if the supply is +/- 10V, then the output will be +10V for 3/4 of the time, and -10V for 1/4 of the time, and the diff-amp's output is the input minus the output, so it's +5V for 3/4 of the time, and -15V for 1/4 of the time, which averages to 0.

Comment: user253751 no comment

Comment: @autodidact but... that was a comment...